# Showing polynomials as products of roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

How do I show rigorously that any polynomial $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...a_1x+a_0$ can be written as $a_n(x-b_1)(x-b_2)...(x-b_n)$ for real $a_i$ and real or complex $b_i$

Comment: This is the fundamental theorem of algebra and there are no "easy basic" proofs, e.g. that just use basic algebra. E.g. completeness of the reals becomes an issue, which plain algebra never talks about. There are some interesting not-too-hard intuitive proofs that use things like a bit of hand-wavy complex analysis or algebraic topology, but that's assuming you know a bit about those subjects.

Comment: @user2566092   Fraid not.

Comment: The hard piece is to show that every real (or complex) polynomial *has a root* in $\Bbb C$. For a first step, accept that and try to conclude by induction.